# Default keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I have to add some text during this activity and I want to show the default keyboard for the starting of one activity til the activity is finished.

So, What should I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

In the AndroidManifest.xml set the android:windowSoftInputMode to "stateAlwaysVisible" for your activity.  Reference, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html.